# Excel 2010 vba Can I reference the result of a worksheetfunction in another formula?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to reference the result of an Application.WorksheetFunction in another Application.WorksheetFunction but keep getting Error 2029.
I'm not familiar with the proper syntax for doing this and am hoping for some help.
My code is as follows:

```
    Set ANoteColID = Application.WorksheetFunction
    ANoteColID = [VLOOKUP('Prior Year'!C4,CollateralData!G3:CZ500,31,0)]
    Set BNoteLookUp = Application.WorksheetFunction
    BNoteColId = [MATCH(ANoteColID &2,(CollateralData!AK3:AK500)&(CollateralData!CZ3:CZ500),0)]
```

Comment: Yes, but not like that. Presumably the VLOOKUP returns a string (or number) and you want to add a 2 to the end and do a match?

Comment: That is correct, SJR.  The VLOOKUP will return a string (collateral ID) and I then want to match that string with a value in CollateralData!AK3:AK500 and the 2 with a value in CollateralData!CZ3:CZ500 on the same row.  The second worksheetfunction is a formulaarray but I want to avoid placing the results in cells in a worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this (untested) As you are using evaluate (equivalent to the square brackets) you don't need to use worksheetfunction at all.

```
ANoteColID = Evaluate("VLOOKUP('Prior Year'!C4,CollateralData!G3:CZ500,31,0)")
BNoteColId = Evaluate("MATCH(" & ANoteColID & "2,(CollateralData!AK3:AK500)&(CollateralData!CZ3:CZ500),0)")
```

Comment: That worked.  I was mucking it up with extra stuff.  Thanks!